# Nullability Specifier 'nonnull' conflicts with existing specifier 'nullable' AppDelegate+FCMPlugin.m

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4, cordova-plugin-fcm

cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated@6.4.1,7.0.8,7.8.0.
I have set IOS_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_VERSION => 7.0.0
"cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {
"FCM_VERSION": "19.0.0",
"GRADLE_TOOLS_VERSION": "3.5.3",
"GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION": "4.3.3",
"SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION": "28.0.0",
"ANDROID_DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ICON": "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
"IOS_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_VERSION":"7.0.0"
}

Answer (score 4):

**Goto**: project/platforms/ios/Hawks Out/Plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/AppDelegate+FCMPlugin.m file Line number 190 or 191 this:

```
(void)messaging:(nonnull FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(nonnull NSString *)deviceToken {
```

**Change line into this:**

```
(void)messaging:(nonnull FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(NSString * _Nullable)deviceToken {
```